# Cartesian equation of a moving rod of shape $ y = f(x)= 10\sqrt x$ that passes rigidly through a fixed ring located at a point $P= (a, f(a))$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, coordinate-systems

---

Note : here I use the square root function as an arbitrary example of a curve moving rgidly through a fixed ring; my final goal would be to do the same thing with a closed curve such as an ellipse.

---

- A rigid rod  has the same shape as function $y= f(x)= 10\sqrt x$ in the $X-Y$ plane, that is, it coincides initially with the curve ( from $x=0$ to, say,  $x= n$). So $(0,\sqrt 0)$ is initially one end of the rod, and  $(n,10 \sqrt n)$ is the other end.

At point $P=(a, f(a))$ is located a ring that is motionless. The ring is already threaded on the rod, and allows the rod to move from right to left. But the ring imposes no deformation to the rod, in such a way that when a point initially located $(b, f(b))$ passes through the rod ( at $(a, f(a))$ )  , the whole rod rotates in order to keep its " curvature" at this point ( i.e. $(b, f(b))$)

- My queston is : what is the cartesian equation of the rod in the cartesian coordinate system centered at $(0,0)$? In other words, ***what is the equation of $y= 10\sqrt x$ when it moves from right to left while passing rigidly through a fixed point $P= (a, f(a))$***, always keeping its original curvature at each point.
- I would say that the transformation amounts to a rotation plus a translation of $b$ units  to the left, when point $Q= (b, f(b))$ is passing through the ring located at $P= (a, f(a))$.

The angle of the rotation, $R$,  is apparently equal to the inclination of the tangent to the curve at $Q= (b, f(b))$, namely $R= \arctan f'(b)$.

***Am I right to suppose that the center of the rotation is $P=(a, f(a))$?***

- The equation I come up with , applying the " rotation about an arbitrary point " formula, and adding a horizontal shift , has a flow since , ***for some high values of $b$, the curve no longer passes through the " ring" at $P= (a, f(a))$.***
- Finally, ***how to produce the  translation ( to the left)  effect*** ? Should the $+b$ be applied to the variable $x$ , or should it be applied to the transformed coordinate $X(x,y)$ taken as a whole?

My equation so far ( here the Desmos construction : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1zsz2ppkwa) :

$$ X(x,y) =  (x-a+b) \cos(R) + ( y-f(a)+f(b)) \sin(R) +a  $$

$$ Y(x,y) =  (y- f(a)+ f(b)) \cos(R) - (x-a+b) \sin(R) +f(a) $$

which yields  for the moving curve/ rod  :

$$Y(x,y) = 10 \sqrt {X(x,y)}. $$

Comment: Tonight I can't answer your question in a detailed way, but I can give you a hint. What you're trying to do is equivalent of keeping fixed the curve ans sliding on it a reference frame attached to the point $P$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

the position vector is:

$$\vec R=\begin{bmatrix}
   x \\
   y(x) \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

thus the tangent vector $~\vec t~$ and the normal vector $~\vec n~$ are

$$\vec t=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   y'(x) \\
 \end{bmatrix}\quad,\vec{n}=\begin{bmatrix}
            -y'(x) \\
            1 \\
          \end{bmatrix}$$

from here you obtain the transformation matrix

$$\mathbf S=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    \hat t & \hat n \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

moving the rod means that

$$ \vec R\mapsto \mathbf S^T(a)\,\begin{bmatrix}
   x \\
   y(x) \\
 \end{bmatrix}_{\,x=b..a}$$